# How to check the previous data that you selected in DatePicker of a specific website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, browser

Is it possible to check the previous data that i selected in the DatePicker of a specific website on Chrome Browser?

I'm trying to retrieve a data that i had selected in the DatePicker before my browser reloaded.

Comment: No, not unless you control that website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your talking about php and php alone or javascript you can use

```
$_SESSION['datepicked']
```

or something like javascript

```
localStorage.setItem(key,value);
```

but like the previous comment said. You CANNOT do anything if you dont control the website